# Calculate x if CD is a diameter of the circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]

I cannot solve question 8c. Any advice on how to solve it?
I was thinking of somehow making CD equal to CP.

Comment: I wonder if there is a mistake in the text: $CD$ diameter or radius ?